# Mysql foreign key, must be matches in referenced table or key is deleted?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-key-relationship

I have a one to many relationship between two tables in mysql.

One called **type** with a primary of url

```
url
varchar(255)
```

And one called **order** with an index on url.

```
url          | id_no
varchar(255) | int
```

The **order** table can have many values in it and there is already a foreign key set up so that if a `url` is deleted in the table **type** it deletes all associated keys with a matching `url` in **order**.

Orders can also be deleted manually meaning that a `url` could exist in **type** that doesn't have a relationship to the table **order**.

Is there a way to set up a foreign key so that if a `url` in **type** does not have a relationship to the table **order** then it will delete itself from **type**?

Looking at the mysql manual I cannot figure it out, I am confused by `CASCADE` as it says it will delete all associated keys, but I only want to delete a `url` from the table **type** if and only if there is no relationship between the two?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that with a `DELETE` trigger on the `order` table: Let it check, if there exist other rows with the same url, and if not delete it from `type`.

Another way to do it is creating a maintenance script similar to

```
DELETE FROM `type` WHERE url NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT `url` FROM `order`
)
```

and run it on a regular or on-demand basis.